# How to use Maps.TMapCircle in Delphi 10 for Android?

Tags: android, delphi, maps

i want to add some `TmapCircle` to my `TMapView` for a Android App. Adding `Marker` works fine. Only `Circles` are not working.
Here is my Code:

```
uses
system.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,
System.Variants,
FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, 
FMX.TabControl, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
FMX.Gestures, System.Actions, FMX.ActnList, FMX.Maps, System.Sensors,
System.Sensors.Components, IdBaseComponent, IdIntercept,System.IOUtils,
IdBlockCipherIntercept, Data.FMTBcd, Data.DB, Data.SqlExpr,   
Data.DbxSqlite, System.Generics.Collections;
...
..
.
private
{ Private declarations }
FMarkers : TList<TMapMarker>;
FCircles : TList<TMapCircle>;
...
..
.
implementation
var
MyMarker : TMapMarkerDescriptor;
MyCircle : TMapCircleDescriptor;
...
..
.

procedure TTabbedwithNavigationForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
Position: TMapCoordinate;
begin

position.Latitude := mapview1.Location.Latitude;
position.Longitude := mapview1.Location.Longitude;

MyMarker := TMapMarkerDescriptor.Create(Position, 'MyMarker');
MyMarker.Draggable := True;
MyMarker.Visible :=True;
Fmarkers.Add(MapView1.AddMarker(MyMarker));


MyCircle := TMapCircleDescriptor.Create(Position, 190);
Mycircle.StrokeWidth := 3;
FCircles.Add(MapView1.AddCircle(MyCircle));
end;
```

`Fmarkers` works fine. But `Fcircles` gives me a Error:

> Segmentation Fault 11

in this line:

```
FCircles.Add(MapView1.AddCircle(MyCircle));
```

I don't understand why.

I am using Rad Studio 10.

Comment: My goal is to select each circle seperately to delete or change propertys from one circle.

Comment: You should rather edit your question than add information as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omit relevant parts of your source code. Please post a *complete* example.

However, I think your initialization code (which you omit) is broken. Most likely, you forgot to create `FCircles`. Thus, an access violation occures which is indicated by the error message "*Segmentation Fault 11*".

Comment: you are right. i have forgot to create fCircle. sorry.